# Transition to Add-in & SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-addin, spfx, farm-solution

Taking the case of a company which works on SharePoint since a while and have engineers trained to develop full-trust solutions. So, they develop full-trust solutions to add functionalities to its farm. Often, functionalities developed are not end-user, not read-only. The company also store sensitive data and they don't want to put their data on the cloud.

In this case, is there a real interest to trained engineers to add-in and SPFx in order to develop new solutions to replace their full-trust solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depend on the Company's decision whether to move to new SharePoint Add-ins and SharePoint Framework.

But

If you are really planning to move your farm solutions to SharePoint Add-ins and SharePoint Framework Add-ins then you must first go through following great content.

> If you have extended your SharePoint environment by using farm
> solutions and you want to migrate your extensions to the SharePoint
> add-in model to make your transition to SharePoint Online easier, you
> need to transform your farm solutions to the SharePoint add-in model.
>
> Transforming your farm solutions to the SharePoint add-in model
> involves analyzing your existing extensions, designing and developing
> your new add-in for SharePoint, and then testing and deploying your
> add-in in your production environment.

Full content : [Transform farm solutions to the SharePoint add-in model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/transform-farm-solutions-to-the-sharepoint-app-model)